# Get command used to start a Docker container

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container running, and I want to create another one similar to it. How can I find out what command was used to start the container? There's `docker inspect`, but I'd have to go through and look at each of the config options one by one.

Edit: I want to get the full command used to start the container, including environment variables, links, volumes, etc. For example:

```
docker run -d --name foo -v /bar:/bar --link baz:baz -e DEBUG=True image bash
```

Comment: try `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Cmd}}' container_id` and also `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Entrypoint}}' container_id`

Comment: @user2915097 why didn't you add that as an answer?

Comment: @user2915097 thanks, but I want the full command, not just the last part - e.g. `docker run -d -v /foo:/bar --link baz:baz image command`

Comment: I mean, links, volumes, environment variables and everything

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774347/789858) solved my case

Answer (score 39):

The following will show the environment variables, the ENTRYPOINT of the Dockerfile, the CMDLINE, the volumes  from, the volumes, the links.

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Env}} {{ .Config.Entrypoint}} {{ .Config.Cmd}} {{ .VolumesFrom}} {{.Volumes}}  {{ .HostConfig.links}}' container_id
```

Comment: like this `docker inspect -f '{{json .Config}}' 2fd | jq '.Env'` for Env, but it will also be a long command with all the parameters , not sure if this is more handy

Comment: This is pretty cool - certainly makes it easier to find the information. But it's not in a format that I could just copy and paste to spawn a new container. I'm considering writing a script to parse the JSON output of `docker inspect` and then format it into a command.

Comment: that jq command is missing volumes.

The original reply does not seem to work on the latest docker 18.09.0 it seems they changed the json locations of the volumes

Comment: @ z0r you should use reckod https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod that reverse engineers a `docker run`

Comment: `Template parsing error: template: :1:61: executing "" at <.VolumesFrom>: map has no entry for key "VolumesFrom"`

Comment: @Nakilon, It means that no volumnes were added and you can try removing that.

Comment: Thanks! Works great on docker version 19. Also, this command can be customised according to the user's docker configuration. Eg, if you don't have volumes configured, you will get error - `Template parsing error: template: :1:61: executing "" at <.VolumesFrom>: map has no entry for key "VolumesFrom"`. Just remove those missing keys accordingly. In my case, even host links were not configured. So, finally the full fledged working command in my environment was: `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Env}} {{ .Config.Entrypoint}} {{ .Config.Cmd}}' 1e8623ed76d4`