# Reconstruct docker run command parameters from container

Tags: docker

What's the best way to reconstruct `docker run` command parameters from existing docker container? I could use `docker inspect` and use the info found there. Is there any better way?

Comment: It does seem like `docker inspect` is the proper tool to inspect running containers. What's wrong with using that? Do you want to talk to the Docker API directly?

Answer (score 5):

Not super easy, but you can do it by formatting the output from `docker inspect`. For a container started with this command:

```
> docker run -d -v ~:/home -p 8080:80 -e NEW_VAR=x --name web3 nginx:alpine sleep 10m
```

You can pull out the volumes, port mapping, environment variables, container name, image name and command with:

```
> docker inspect -f "V: {{.Mounts}} P: {{.HostConfig.PortBindings}} E:{{.Config.Env}} NAME: {{.Name }} IMAGE: {{.Config.Image}} COMMAND: {{.Path}} {{.Args}}" web3
```

That gives you the output:

```
V: [{ /home/scrapbook /home   true rprivate}] P: map[80/tcp:[{ 8080}]] E:[NEW_VAR=x PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin NGINX_VERSION=1.11.5] NAME: /web3 IMAGE: nginx:alpine COMMAND: sleep [10m]
```

Which is a start.

Docker Captain [Adrian Mouat](https://twitter.com/adrianmouat) has an excellent blog post on formatting the output: [Docker Inspect Template Magic](http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/).

Answer (score 0):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container) which links to a tool which programmatically derives the `docker run` command from a container.