# Migrating existing containers from Hyper-V to WSL2 technology

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

After DockerCon 2020, I enthusiastically downloaded Windows 10 2004 and tried to upgrade Docker Desktop to WSL 2 containers and experiment.

I had a few containers, in particular a couple of databases **along with their data** stored within volumes. Postgres and MS SQL Server in the case.

I wouldn't like to lose the data, though it's not critical. I used Docker volumes rather than OS mounts because I have repeatedly seen that using Windows mounts for database data storage is **not** recommended.

When I enabled WSL-2 for the first time, all my containers and volumes disappeared.

I'd like to ask if there is any (recommended) procedure or tool to mgirate Hyper-V based containers to WSL-2 along with their data.

Images can be easily redownloaded. How about container setup and data migration to WSL-2?

Of course I **can** do it manually. I **can** dump the volumes to my local drive (as a tar) using `busybox` and restore using another busybox instance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, here is my sharing of experience.

### Reconstruct the docker `run` syntax

First, you need to remember or reconstruct the syntax to start the container to re-run them later. The idea is to collect as much information as possible from existing containers to re-run them

Here is a good [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277699/reconstruct-docker-run-command-parameters-from-container)

### Migrating volumes

That's between ease of execution and long-running task. Easy because it took me simply one container, long and tedious because it requires multiple commands

```
docker run `
           --rm ` #Dispose after use
           -v G:\Docker:/volumes ` # Mount my Windows drive so that the file will appear in Explorer
           - v src_mount:/src ` # e.g. mssql2017:/mssql2017 mounts mssql2017 named volume to Busybox
           busybox `
           tar -zcvf /volumes/backup_name.tar.gz /src
```

Rinse and repeat for all named volumes of your interest. I had a bunch only

### Dump images you won't be able/willing to reconstruct

In my case, Oracle 12c/19c were built but never pushed. Building Oracle is painful becuase you have to build the container after downloading their licensed ZIP file

Use `docker save -o` wisely. Example

```
docker save oracledb:12.0.0.0c -o oracledb.img
```

### Restore images

After switching to WSL-2, use `docker load` wisely

### Restore volumes

Manually recreate all volumes with `docker volume create` and unzip with busybox. This is kind of a reverse

```
docker run `
       --rm ` #Dispose after use
       -v G:\Docker:/volumes ` # Mount my Windows drive so that the file will appear in Explorer
       - v dest_mount:/dest ` # e.g. mssql2017:/mssql2017 mounts mssql2017 named volume to Busybox
       busybox `
       tar -zxvf /volumes/backup_name.tar.gz /dest
```

### Restore containers

Now that you have your source Docker commandline-s, launch them to recreate containers.

**Conclusion**: I am thinking about making a reusable Powershell script

Comment: Did you ever create that script?  I just switched to wsl2 tonight and have a TON of named volumes on my hyper v vm. 

Comment: Of course never. I know that I promise myself to do a lot of things... but I have a TON of work to care about

Comment: One hint about reconstructing the docker run syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container links to a tool which programmatically derives the `docker run` command from a container.