# Lost all docker containers and images after upgrading docker

Tags: docker

I upgraded my docker to 2.5.0.1 in windows after upgrading I lost all containers and images
Is there any way to recover them?
Why they lost?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You aren't alone. This seems to be a common occurrence with Docker. A very quick search reveals the following, which may be helpful:

- [All volumes, containers and images gone after update to 1.13.0](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1175)
- [All images gone after upgrade to 2.1.0](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3772)
- [Docker deletes all my files on WSL2 where containers have linked volumes](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8412)
- [Lost all my images and containers after upgrading to version 2.0.0.0-mac78 (28905)](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3362)

This happened to me as well. I haven't used docker in several months, but I had several images locally. I went to use it today, and saw the same thing - all but one of my images in Linux, and one in Windows, are gone. I used to have nothing but good things to say about docker, but this is a cause for concern.

**Update**

I use Docker for Windows. I can find the original images if I modify Docker to use the legacy Hyper-V backend, rather than the WSL 2 based engine.

- Open up Docker Desktop
- Click on Settings
- Uncheck "Use the WSL 2 based engine"
- Click "Apply & Restart"

I found this setting after the OP mentioned disabling WSL completely on their system. The question now becomes [how do we convert these images so that they are supported by the WSL 2 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131415/migrating-existing-containers-from-hyper-v-to-wsl2-technology)?

Comment: I found that by turning off WSL2 my problem fixed

Comment: @WebMaster Do you mean you disabled the WSL feature completely, or you reverted from WSL2 to WSL1. Can you state exactly what you did for future users?

Comment: I disabled completly and back to hyper-v, As I created my containers in hyper-v

Comment: Also if you get stuck with settings hanging, open a powershell and switch daemons first: & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCLI.exe' -SwitchDaemon

Comment: This has just happened to me and this answer allowed me to resolve my issue. Just one minor note, the Apply & Restart button was grayed out so I closed down the dialog using the X and then restarted Docker to find all was well

Comment: It occur in Mac ( M1 ). I don't have that options. looks like a common issue

Comment: This happened to me when making a big jump in versions. I am curious if you could keep your original images/containers if you were willing to spend the time stepping through the versions? Of course that's assuming you thought to make a backup. ;)

Comment: I also upgraded and lost my containers, any way to keep them while switching to WSL 2?

Answer (score 3):

What kind of containers are you running on Windows (Linux Containers / Windows Containers )?

Maybe you unintentionally switch that setting and now is showing the other ones.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#settings check that on the tray icon.

Comment: Linux containers

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the docker root folder is changed. I had that issue

Answer (score 0):

```
/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

This row will be overwritten:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --data-root /THISISGONE
```