# Windows: How to migrate project databases from Docker Hyper-V backend to WSL2 backend

Tags: ddev

I have projects in windows but when i upgraded docker to work with wsl 2 then i have to run ddev commands from wsl console and db containers have empty database.

One way to to migrate dbs is to dump from old container and the import into new container. But is there a way to do this automatically for all projects? or atleast project by project.

Answer (score 1):

Start the project in hyper-v docker environment and start up the project like `ddev start`. After running up the project then there are 2 ways to import the project either by taking a snapshot or exporting sql format which is more portable ( in case you want to setup project elsewhere other than ddev ).

To take snapshot you can use `ddev snapshot` command and it will make a db snapshot under .ddev/db_snapshots folder. Then you can copy it from there and place it in wsl2 project dir under the same dir like .ddev/db_snapshots. After that run `ddev restore-snapshot` [snapshot name]. for more docs https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/cli-usage/#snapshotting-and-restoring-a-database

Other method is to use ddev export-db from the old project dir and then using ddev import-db in the new project dir under wsl2. Export command docs https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/cli-usage/#exporting-a-database Import command docs https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/cli-usage/#importing-a-database

Comment: Thanks for this! It's possible to migrate docker volumes from Hyper-V to WSL2 backends as well, using the strategies in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131415/migrating-existing-containers-from-hyper-v-to-wsl2-technology - but I think your way is far more straightforward. It's not necessary at all to migrate containers, as they'll be recreated just fine.