# Any way to retrieve the command originally used to create a Docker container?

Tags: docker

This question seems to have been often asked, but I cannot find any answer that correctly and clearly specifies how to accomplish this.

I often create test docker containers that I run for a while.  Eventually I stop the container and restart it simply using `docker start <name>`.  However, sometimes I am looking to upgrade to a newer image, which means deleting the existing container and creating a new one from the updated image.

I've been looking for a reliable way to retrieve the original 'docker run' command that was used to create the container in the first place.  Most responses indicate to simply use `docker inspect` and look at the `Config.Cmd` element, but that is not correct.

For instance, creating a container as:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Qwerty123<(*' -e TZ=America/Toronto -p 1433:1433 -v c:/dev/docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql --name mssql -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

using docker inspect will show:

```
$ docker inspect mssql | jq -r '.[0]["Config"]["Cmd"]'
[
  "/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"
]
```

There are many [issues created on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15614) for this same request, but all have been closed since the info is already in the `inspect` output - one just has to know how to read it.

Has anyone created a utility to easily rebuild the command from the output of the `inspect` command?  All the responses that I've seen all refer to the wrong info, notably inspecting the `Config.Cmd` element, but ignoring the `Mounts`, the `Config.Env`, `Config.ExposedPorts`, `Config.Volumes`, etc elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are few utilities out there which can help you.

Give it a try

https://github.com/bcicen/docker-replay

https://github.com/lavie/runlike

If you want to know more such cool tools around docker check this https://github.com/veggiemonk/awesome-docker

Answer (score 1):

Of course docker inspect is the way to go, but if you just want to "reconstruct" the docker run command, you have

https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod

it says

Reverse engineer a docker run command from an existing container (via docker inspect).

Another way is Christian G answer at

[How to show the run command of a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container/35727886#35727886)

using bash-preexec

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and ended up looking at .bash_history file to find the command I used.
This would give you all the docker create commands you'd run;

```
grep 'docker create' .bash_history
```

Note: if you ran docker create in that same session you'll need to logout/login for the .bash_history to flush to disk.