# last used docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

Let's say I have started my containers with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.localhost.yml up --build
```

Is there a way to lookup, for a given running container, what the command was that started it? Something (pseudocode) like `docker origin-command <container id>` or similar?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container

Comment: What exactly are you looking to find out? This might help: "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.localhost.yml config" => it will show you the final merged configuration that will be run by docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can. 
use the `inspect` docker command:

`docker container inspect <container_id>`

this command will output a huge json object, what you need is under `Config.CMD` which appears to be an array containing the container entrypoint command and its flags.

Comment: this is close enough to what i needed