# How to print cmd line arguments after attaching to docker container running process?

Tags: docker, command-line

I want to see the command prompt used to trigger a python script inside a docker container. The process that is running can only be stopped if there is a dire need.

Is there any way I can see what was command line that was used?

To attach to the docker container I use this command.

```
docker attach [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container/32774347 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER ps aux
```

to see the process which is running in container

Answer (score 1):

You can see the docker logs for the same. **sudo docker logs ContainerID/image_name:tag**

rolling logs **sudo docker logs -f ContainerID/image_name:tag**