# How to derive "docker run" syntax from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-run

I ran a `docker run` on a docker image with a long convoluted command syntax that I have since forgotton and lost. Is there any way to derive the syntax that ran a container given the container ID?

I know `docker inspect` can give you information about the container but I was hoping the `docker run` syntax would be saved somewhere.

Comment: Store all the run parameters in a [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file and you will never have to worry about forgetting them again.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator), this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container), but just adding it here for completeness:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    assaflavie/runlike <Your_Container_ID>
```