# Can we know the docker run command used to start a running container?

Tags: docker

I have a container running in my ubuntu machine. I want to know the exact docker run command that was used to start that container. It is running since a long time and I don't remember what parameters were used to start that container.

Comment: there are many commands/parameters  used for each case , but generally you run the image and put the ip address

Comment: Did you try the solutions mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, the accepted answers works! Though we need to note that it gives some parameters which are implicitly added the docker run command along with the ones the user provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the relevant run parameters for the container with:

`sudo cat /var/lib/docker/containers/$(docker container inspect <container id> | jq -r .[0].Id)/config.v2.json | jq`

Comment: This gives all the parameters of the container, but I want the ones which are explicitly provided in the docker run command. Anyway that works as long as we know the list of parameter names to be passed.

Comment: [runlike](https://github.com/lavie/runlike/) is a great tools, however, work is in-progress to implement all the possible RUN parameters. If you are not sure which parameter was left out, my answer will tell you where to find the gap.