# docker modify start parameters of exist stopped container

Tags: windows, docker, config, elk, docker-desktop

I use `sudo docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 5044:5044 -it --name elk sebp/elk` command to run a elk container, and has populated many data to the container, but it cannot start now.

And I guess it's caused by one service named logstash in the container, so I want to start the container without start the logstash service.

There is one parameter `-e LOGSTASH_START=0` to make the container not start the service, when create a new container.

How can I apply it to the exist container? I use windows docker-desktop 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the data is kept in the container you can try `docker cp elk:/data/path/in/elk/container /target/path/on/host` to move it out.

Otherwise you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999675/14704799) to find the equivalent config.v2.json on Windows; add the `LOGSTASH_START=0` to the "Env" array (**Note** no -e required).