# start a new docker container with the same settings

Tags: docker

sounds simple, but I haven't found an easy way - I have docker containers written by me on a NAS - for 3rd party ones I just use watchtower, but for my own I just want to "upgrade" the container each time I change the docker file.

ie - I want to create a new container with the same name and *all the same settings*

I tried writing this upgrade.sh - but it doesn't work at all.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this shell script?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get container settings
settings=$(docker inspect --format='{{json .Config}}' $1)

# Stop container
docker stop $1

# Delete old container if it exists
if [ "$(docker ps -aqf name=$1_old)" ]; then
    docker rm $1_old
fi

# Rename old container
docker rename $1 $1_old

# Create new container with extracted settings
docker create --name $1 --restart always $settings

# Start new container
docker start $1
```

in most cases I've created or updated the settings using the docker gui - so saying "just write a script that has the settings in it" is not a solution.  I want to *read* the settings - ie port, volume and environment mappings and apply them to the new container.

Comment: What "doesn't work at all?"

Comment: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Comment: Enrich your question with this information.  An actual error message might help, too.

Comment: Are you trying to [Get command used to start a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955001/get-command-used-to-start-a-docker-container)?